# Need to filter repeated HTML element

Tags: javascript, php

Suppose i have a HTML like below:

```
<div class="row">
    <section>
        <section>
            <section>
            <p> My Content </p>     
            </section>      
        </section>  
    </section>
</div>
```

I need out put like this.

```
<div class="row">
    <section>
        <p> My Content </p>                     
    </section>
</div>
```

How it can be possible with PHP DOM CLASS or JAVASCRIPT ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What difference does it make?

Comment: I want to remove extra elements because it makes design issue.

Comment: How did you generate the original HTML?

Comment: That is not a question. I need a solution. do you have any idea.?

Comment: why cant you remove the section tags manually handy?

Comment: If it can then why i am asking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a simple function using **jquery** that should be able to solve your problem

```
function refactorByTag(tagName){
    var repeat =false;
    var parent =false;
    var children =false;
    do{
        $(tagName).each(function(index, el) {
            if(!$(this).parent(tagName).length && !$(this).children('section').length){
                parent = false;
                children = false;
                repeat = false;
            }
            else{
                if(!$(this).parent(tagName).length) parent = $(this);
                if(!$(this).children(tagName).length) children = $(this);

                if(parent != false && children != false){
                    repeat = true;
                    parent.replaceWith(children);
                    parent = false;
                    children = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }while(repeat);
}
```

Basically will check each tagname you choose if has a parent and child and then replace the parent for the corresponding child.

This will loop the entire document and will only stop when all elements with same tag remains without parent.

Might be simpler if you read the code instead of my words :)

Here is an working sample
https://jsfiddle.net/Lnztpy7a/2/

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem, in order to help others too.